# Display popup before detail change

Tags: routes, sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm developing SAP FIORI-like application using Master-Master-Detail template from WEB IDE (including routing etc.). On "Detail" view there are some segmented buttons, that user uses to assess the products quality.

What I need is to check before user navigates to other detail (choosing other item from master2 list, or going back to master1 view) if any of buttons was selected (changed). If yes popup should be displayed to confirm exit without saving results.

I tried to use "onSelect" function in "master2" view, but:

1. I don't now how to read values from current detail (to check, if anything was changed (selected)),
2. How to prevent from selection of "new" element on the master2 list.

Which event in which view should I use?

Comment: Can you provide code snippets?

Comment: Are you using Routing or navigation using App.to?

Comment: I using Routing by MyRouter like here: [link](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/68/8f36bd758e4ce2b4e682eef4dc794e/content.htm?fullscreen=true)

Answer (score 0):

You need to the following:

**1.Capture the change**

On change/activity on buttons, you need to have flag(say `dataChanged`) set at **app** level so that you know something has been edited by user across views.
For `button`, you can capture using [press](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Button.html#event:press) event. `// tap is deprecated`
and for list make use of [selectionChange](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html#event:selectionChange) event.

**2. Handle routing in detail and also in master2 view also**

In detail **&** master2 page make use of `onRouteMatched` method. Before routing, you know the flag and the routing name. You can desired actions.
example:

```
onRouteMatched : function(oEvent) {     
    var sName = oEvent.getParameter("name");
//Open popup for confirmation based on sName and dataChanged values.. Better make this as reusable so that you can reuse.
}
```

> Please note that there are two possibilities as you already mentioned.
>   User navigating to different master view OR navigating new item in the
>   master list2. Both scenarios have to be handled. **onRouteMatched** is
>   the best place to handle it.